# Extracting content from a dynamic web site using a Java Library

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

I am looking for a Java Library that supports web-scraping with Java Script to extract web content representing apartments to rent from this dynamic web-page:

https://www.immowelt.at/liste/wien-2-leopoldstadt/wohnungen/mieten?sort=price

In my case I see in the browser a total of 20 apartments to rent, but when opening the "View Page Source" of the browser, I see there only the first 4 apratments as a HTML code (they are under the CSS selector "listitem clear relative js-listitem").

Using JSoup I am able to extract the content of the first 4 aprtaments, but how to extract the rest of 16 apartments as Java Objects ?

Comment: You can launch a browser, like selenium, preferably in headless mode

Comment: If Firefox I can see all the elements in the HTML code if I use `Inspect Element`